# How to read a table with blank cells in common lisp

Tags: excel, csv, common-lisp

I have to read a large csv table with blank cells using ACL. Each cell in a row is related to a particular property of the object named by the first cell. I use a loop with read-line but blank cells are considered as spaces and this messes all property list. Could anyone have a solution to this problem ? Thank you

Comment: Start by using a CSV library. `(ql:system-apropos "csv")` gives quite a few that you could look into.

Comment: without an example what your doing, it is difficult to help. Show you code and an example.

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are correct that this is vaguer than StackOverflow expects, but I'll take a crack at it.

I assume you have some reason not to use a standard csv package (efficiency, perhaps, if you're doing custom processing while reading each line rather than just reading it all in and then manipulating it?), so I won't mention those.

Still, without information on your specific use case, all I can give you is a simple loop for reading the csv file, using the `cl-ppcre` package (available on quicklisp) to split each line by the commas. You can modify it as necessary to use different delimiters, try to read some strings as special values (e.g. integers and floats), process the first element differently as you mention you need to, etc.

```
(defun read-csv (filename)
  (with-open-file (f filename)
    (let ((ptrn (cl-ppcre:create-scanner ",( *|)")))
      (loop for line = (read-line f nil)
            while line
            collect
            (let* ((line (string-trim (list #\
) line))) 
;; The above trims the newline character from the end of each line. 
;; It shows up as ^M in my editor, in case StackOverflow borks the character codes and you need to type it manually.
              (cl-ppcre:split ptrn line))))))
```

Usage:

```
;;; Returns a list of lists
;;; Each sublist contains the elements in one line of the CSV file
(uiop:with-current-directory ((uiop:getcwd)) ;; Replace with the name of your directory
     (read-csv "csv-read-manual.csv")) ;; Replace with the name or relative path of your csv
```